# Controlling Pianobar via IREXEC

Tags: audio, remote

I've set up pianobar using the [Adafruit instructions](http://learn.adafruit.com/pi-wifi-radio/overview) with the exception of the LCD panel.  I also have my IR remote working using lirc and [these instructions](http://alexba.in/blog/2013/01/06/setting-up-lirc-on-the-raspberrypi/).  I can get `irexec` to do simple shell commands such as `mpg321 song.mp3` and even start pianobar by setting something like this in my `.lircrc` file:

```
begin
  button = KEY_F 
  prog = irexec
  repeat = 0
  config = pianobar
end
```

(In the above, my KEY_F is mapped to the `FM` key on my IR remote.)  I'd like to map volume up and down (pianobar uses `(` and `)` for volume control) and quit `q` to keys on the remote, however setting `prog = echo "q"` or `prog = q` don't pass those buttons to pianobar.  Does anyone have any experience with controlling pianobar with an IR remote?  I don't have to use `irexec` but that's about where my knowledge caps out at the moment.

Comment: Just re-read the instruction on the page you linked to. You need to have lirc learn what ir-codes are generated by the other keys on the remote, and what keyboard-key it needs to assign to them. You can get a list of available keys by running the `irrecord --list-namespace` command. You don't have to add to to `.lircrc`, as lirc will just make them behave like keyboard presses.

Comment: @Gerben true, I can assign the various keys of my IR-remote to the keys that pianobar is expecting, but pianobar doesn't know to look for keypresses from the IR receiver, so there's something else missing.

Comment: When I setup the keys on my remote and used something like `KEY_7`, when I pressed the key on the remote, the number 7 would appear on the console. Just as if I were to press the 7 on the keyboard. So lirc will kind of simulate a keyboard. So in my case I had to rename the keys to none-predefined once, to prevent this unwanted behavior. But in your case that is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Gerben Can you elaborate on your system further?  I don't get the same response, but I am also accessing my RPi via SSH so am not looking at the console per se.

Comment: Via SSH you wouldn't see this output. I don't really recall anything else, besides what I posted here above. As it wasn't what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can also control pianobar from the command line, instead of the UI. I see a file called [`remote.sh`](https://raw.github.com/PromyLOPh/pianobar/214050e0567f1d152a001c7dd0ee903c6039ce37/contrib/remote.sh) in the git-repository. Either find it in your filesystem, or just copy and past in into your own `remote.sh` file.

To let the remote select the next song, add the following in your .lircrc file

```
begin
  button = NAME_YOU_GAVE_BUTTON_IN_IRRECORD 
  prog = irexec
  repeat = 0
  config = /path/to/remote.sh next
end
```

remote.sh is very limited it what you can do with it, but I wouldn't be surprised if you could just add other option.

for volume-up you could use

```
begin
  button = NAME_YOU_GAVE_BUTTON_IN_IRRECORD 
  prog = irexec
  repeat = 0
  config = amixer set Master 5+
end
```